# Suffix question -ive, -tive, -ative and -ion, -tion, -ation

Tags: suffixes

It looks as if there's a rule of suffix change between -ive and -ion, -tive and -tion, -ative and -ation. Is it a constant rule?

I know the relationship between -ize, -ism and -ist.
Is there any other suffix rule like this?

Comment: *It looks as if there's a rule*: “There are no rules in English, only guidance. Some guidance looks like a rule; it probably isn't."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be careful.

Sometimes, the suffix change to your first English word doesn't give you an English word. For example primitive (no such word as primition).

Sometimes there is a related English word, but it has a different form. For example: expensive->expense (not *expension).

Sometimes, the suffix change to your first English word gives you a second English word, but its meaning isn't related to the first word's meaning. For example positive->position; objective->objection.

Comment: Oh, my God. It is the most valuable and interesting in the English study life.

Answer (score 0):

These are the same rule, if it is a rule.

The suffixes are ***-ive*** and ***-ion***, and everything before that (eg *immers-, elect-, operat-*) is the root. The present participle suffix *-ing* is added to the root too.